# What is an easy way to setup authenticated HTTP or SOCKS proxy?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy

What is an easy way to setup authenticated HTTP or SOCKS proxy on Ubuntu Natty? None of the simple proxy servers (e.g. tinyproxy) support authentication and I could not seem to get dante working.

Answer (score 2):

OpenSSH has built-in support for SOCKS proxies.

`ssh -D 8080 <proxy_server>`

Then within your application set the SOCKS proxy server to `localhost` with port `8080`.

Comment: I am trying to run a proxy server, not connect to one.

Comment: ... and it should be able to connect to it from a standard web browser.

Comment: @user492922 This makes use of OpenSSH's support for dynamic port redirection so that traffic can be tunneled through the ssh connection. It can be used with any application that supports SOCKS v4 or v5 proxies.

Comment: I am trying to create <proxy_server> not connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

Authentication is [trivial](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Authentication) to set up in squid. Did you try that?

Comment: I was hoping for something more trivial to configure than squid.